# Xdebug 2.7.2 Centos 7.3.2 PHP not supported problem

Tags: xdebug

I am trying to install Xdebug 2.7.2. on a Centos7 machine with php 7.2.3 installed.

When I am running ./configure the process stops with error and the following output

```
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable Xdebug support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable Xdebug developer build flags... no
checking Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.4.0 (found 5.6.33)
```

I can not find php 5.6 installed on my machine.

From command line php -v shows me "php 7.2.23" and from local joomla installation I see on on system info that I am using php 7.2.23.

When I look for installed php through yum this is what I get:

```
[root@192 etc]# yum list installed | grep php
php.x86_64                            7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-cli.x86_64                        7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-common.x86_64                     7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-devel.x86_64                      7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-fedora-autoloader.noarch          1.0.0-1.el7                    @epel      
php-gd.x86_64                         7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-json.x86_64                       7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-mbstring.x86_64                   7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-opcache.x86_64                    7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-pdo.x86_64                        7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-pear.noarch                       1:1.10.9-3.el7.remi            @remi-php72
php-process.x86_64                    7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-sqlsrv.x86_64                     5.6.1-2.el7.remi.7.2           @remi-php72
php-xml.x86_64                        7.2.23-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
```

I dont know where awk find php 5.6 and stops the installation of xdebug.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using php 7.2 from **remi-php72** repository, you can simply install most of extensions from the same repository. No need to build anything.

See the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

In short:

```
# yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
# yum install php-pecl-xdebug
```